# document.getElementsByClassName('word')[0].click() works on h3 but doesn't work for div

Tags: javascript

Is `document.getElementsByClassName('word')[0].click()` not working for classes inside of a div ?

I'm using this Javascript code to click on elements that have a class that contains a 'word'. This works perfectly for the h3 elements in the page but now I need to use this for div elements in my page too. I can't seem to get it to work.

The working javascript for h3:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('word')[0].click()
```

UPDATE: Apparently I can't use .click() on div elements. As a child there is an em element that has that div as a parrent. I will need to add code to the click() is done on that child em element.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName() does not do partial class matches, the exact class must be present.

By doing `document.getElementsByClassName('word')[0]` you are getting the first result only.
In your browser's console does `document.getElementsByClassName('word')` come back with an array containing h3, div, etc?
If it does, you should loop over the results instead of using just the first one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. document.getElementsByClassName() does partial class matches, and yes, I loop over it. for (var i = 0; i < 20; i ++){document.getElementsByClassName("word")[0].click();} but it only gives me the ones in h3 and not the ones in div

Comment: By no partial matches, I mean `class='test-word-test'` would not be matched by your selector but `class='test word'` would, because both the class `test` and`word` are present on that element. The spaces mean a new class.

Comment: Yes,  the array contains all the ones in but the ones that are in the DIV my .click isn't working and on the H3 elements it is.

Comment: Did you change the 0 reference to i, your variable?

Comment: Yes, didn't change anything. Cheers

Comment: Please update your question with a code sample of how you are registering the click handler to the divs.

Comment: Ok I will, apparently, I can't click on a div. As a child there is a em element and I should put the javascript click() on that.

Answer (score 0):

In Current window context you can use

```
var classNameArr = window.document.getElementsByClassName('classname');
```

May this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is not your div.click() , it works fine as below,
https://jsfiddle.net/roolearngear/og7yxbyf/1/

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
document.getElementsByClassName("word")[i].click();
}
```

how does your code work specifically?

Comment: Hi thanks, I've checked your code. It looks indeed like the problem is not my div.click :-) thank you for that. hmpfr.